# PHP: report table with date gaps

Tags: php, datetime, report

I have a table in DB which contains summaries for days. Some days may not have the values.
I need to display table with results where each column is a day from user selected range.
I've tried to play with timestamp (end_date - start_date / 86400 - how many days in report, then use DATEDIFF(row_date, 'user_entered_start_date') and create array from this indexes), but now I've got whole bunch of workarounds for summer time :( Any examples or ideas how to make this correct?

P.S. I need to do this on PHP side, because DB is highly loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the DateTime object:

```
$reportdate=date_create($user_startdate);
$interval=new DateInterval('P1D');//1 day interval

$query="SELECT s.start_date, s.end_date, s.info 
   FROM summary s 
   WHERE s.start_date>='$user_startdate' 
      AND s.end_date<='$user_enddate'";

$r=mysqli_query($db,$query);
while($row=$r->fetch_assoc()){
  $rowdate=create_date($row['start_date']);
  while($reportdate < $rowdate) {//won't work if $rowdate is a timestamp!  
    //output $reportdate and blank row
    $reportdate->add($interval); //increment date
  }
  //output $rowdate and $row[info]
  $reportdate->add($interval); //increment date

}
```

ETA another option:

Based on your comments, it may be easier to dynamically generate the missing dates.  For this you'll need an integer table, the number of dates that should appear in your report output, a start date and a date increment.

In your db create a table called `numbers` and insert the numbers 0 through 9:

```
CREATE TABLE  numbers (
  num int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (num)
);
```

The numbers table can be used for making sequences of integers. For instance, to get a sequence from 1 to 20:

```
SELECT i FROM (
  SELECT 10*n1.num + n2.num AS i 
  FROM numbers n1 CROSS JOIN numbers n2) nums
WHERE i BETWEEN 1 AND 20
ORDER BY i ASC;
```

If you left join a sequence query like the above to your regular query, you should be able to generate both real and blank rows. e.g.

```
SELECT alldates.d, mystuff.* FROM
    (SELECT date_add($start_date, interval i day) AS d FROM 
        (SELECT 10*n1.num + n2.num AS i
         FROM numbers n1 CROSS JOIN numbers n2
         ORDER BY i ASC) nums
     WHERE i <= DATEDIFF($end_date,$start_date)) alldates
LEFT JOIN mystuff
ON alldates.d = mystuff.somedate
ORDER BY $whatever;
```

Comment: @Daniel: not sure what you're asking.  DateTime and DateInterval documentation can be found here: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: i have multiple values, so i'll have to maintain $reportdate for each of them, also result is returned ordered by another field (and that must be so) so $rowdate in first row may be higher than $reportdate while next row will be < $reportdate. idea is interesting, but thats not my case :(

Comment: @Daniel: if you post an example of your desired output, it will be easier to help you. I'm unclear as to whether your "multiple values" mean that each record has several dates (problematic) or that each row has a different date (this method will work fine for that as long as the rows are ordered by that date).

Comment: this query will kill my db. atm it has ~1k writes per minute + existing ~850000 records. i did a plain stupid solution using your suggestions: http://pastebin.com/rcaqiLnP - takes about 20M of memory, but works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could "pre-load" the database with blank values.  Then do UPDATE queries instead of inserts.  All your days with no data will be pre-populated.  You can create a simple script that creates a month's/year's/decade's worth of (blank) data and run it as often as you need.  Then you never have to worry about how the days with no data get into the database - you start with your data "zeroed" out.

Comment: I thought about that, but DB becomes huge and really slow. (atm with gaps there are ~870000 records, adding blanks leads to ~2500000 records)

Comment: Ahh, you have *lots* of blanks to fill in.  In that case, you need to handle this as you process the data after retrieval, which sounds like what you're working on.  The best result will probably be to process the data you get from the database into some structure that handles the blanks automatically, like an object that can return real data and fill in "blank" data when there is none.

Comment: What i have atm would be ok unless i would have to check daylight saving time :( I've got array with size = days + 1 filled with '-' for blanks, after that i'm using DATEDIFF result and just set specific indexes in that array. But once again dst issue... code is awful.